# Book about two boys who crash into a cave, and an alien life form protects them but wont let them leave?

Tags: books, aliens, spaceship

Trying to find a book I read in highschool in the early-mid 90's, and it may have been part of the highschool reading list (in australia) .I vaguely remember that one or two boys crash into a cave (or something like this) and it is inhabited by an alien life form which creates a paradise for them. Then later it sabotages their effort to return home and won't let them leave.

Answer (score 9):

I found it!!
The book is "The Lotus Caves" by John Christopher, first published in 1969. [Wikipedia's synopsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lotus_Caves):

> Two teenage boys, Marty and Steve, live in a colony on the Moon, "The Bubble", in the year 2068.Exploring outside the dome of "The Bubble" is strictly controlled. The boys grow bored and decide to explore outside the proscribed area in a stolen lunar vehicle, and crash through the moon's surface into a series of underground caverns containing alien life forms, controlled by a single intelligent alien life form. They also meet a man, a missing early lunar settler, who came to the caves years ago, who has become enthralled by the alien. The boys are torn between staying in the caves, within which the alien provides for their needs, and escaping. They eventually escape, but the man decides to stay, having lost any desire beyond communing with the alien.