# Young adult science fiction I read in the 80's: boy goes underground trying to rescue father from plant

Tags: story-identification

The hero is a young teen-aged boy who I think lives underground. His father goes on an expedition and never returns. The boy takes a ship that can travel underground and finds his father's ship. He finds his father is alive, but his father cannot tear himself from a living plant — it's like he is under control. The boy is able to rescue him at night when the plants are not performing photosynthesis. However, when the boy and his father are in the ship, the plant breaks through the rocks and takes the father. The boy is able to return home without his father.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Can you remember anything more about this book - was it a novel or short story, was it in English, was it set on Earth or an imaginary world? Every detail can help! You might be interested to read [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on asking story-ID questions.

Answer (score 1):

The latter parts of the answer are definitely a description of *[The Lotus Caves](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?13184)* by John Christopher.  The first part of is somewhat different, so you may be misremembering or confabulating two different stories.  *The Lotus Caves* has previously come up [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174215/ya-scifi-moon-colony-story/174216#174216) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35843/book-about-two-boys-who-crash-into-a-cave-and-an-alien-life-form-protects-them/35844#35844).

[image: Original Cover Art]

In *The Lotus Caves*, there are two boys, Marty and Steve, living on the moon, who go out exploring and eventually end up in a closed system of caverns that are filled with various parts of a gigantic intelligent plant.  They want to escape, and they want to take Andrew Thurgood, an older man who has been living there for decades, with them.  (It was finding Thurgood's diary earlier in the book that led the boys to the caverns.)  However, Thurgood has no family connection to either of the boys.

The escape, as you describe it, is exactly out of Christopher's book though.  They wait until the plant has pulled in the "flower" that it uses to collect solar energy, and the whole entity has gone dormant.  They convince the Thurgood to help them find an closed-off exit, where they can break through to the outside.  (Convincing him is not easy; after many years there, eating the plant's drugged food and subject to its hypnotic powers, Thurgood worships and plant and has no desire to leave.)  Moreover, even after they all make it out, the plant wakes up and Thurgood goes back into the caves; whether this is entirely of his own volition or psychically summoned by the plant is ambiguous.