# YA SciFi moon colony story

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I’ve been trying to remember the name of a YA book I read in the mid 80’s. The protagonist was a pre-teen boy, I think he was on a moon colony with his family. It might have been a colony on another planet though. He goes exploring in some caverns and finds an alien life form, something that looks like a beautiful flowering plant, that has mind control powers. It’s got an older man, who’s been missing from the colony, in its thrall. It had a golden age sci-fi sort of feel. I read it just after reading This Place Has No Atmosphere, a sort of YA chick lit sci-fi about a girl who moves to a moon colony, so they might have been published around the same time, but the one I can’t remember might be older.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Answer (score 17):

This is *[The Lotus Caves](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?13184)*, by John Christopher, published in 1969.
It's tied with *The City of Gold and Lead* for my favorite work by Christopher (a.k.a. Samuel Youd).

The most common cover image was this:

[image: The Lotus Caves]

Per Goodreads:

> Fleeing the claustrophobic artificiality of the Moon Bubble, 14-year-olds Marty & Steve illegally reconnoiter-the long-abandoned 1st Station &, following a clue in the journal of "never recovered" Andrew Thurgood, plunge their mechanical crawler into a fragrant, fertile warren of caves. There the enveloping moss & branches, the moving, metamorphosizing leaves & undergrowth are all part of one gigantic sentient Plant which has also provided, for the surviving Thurgood, a lush earth-like orchard & an orchestra tree programmed to play his favorite (now 70-year-old) tunes. The Plant will pamper them until, like the Odyssey's lotus-eaters, they'll relinquish all thoughts of escape. Marty's fight against euphoria, which involves arousing the lethargic, Plant-worshipping Thurgood, is quickly told—more quickly than the Lunarians-at-school episode at the beginning.