# Kids getting lost on the moon

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read a book in 6th grade for school and I can't remember the title. It involved people living under domes on the moon. A couple of kids ended up stealing/taking a key that took them outside the dome to another dome by some sort of vehicle. I only remember them being in a weird but beautiful alienish garden.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  What year were you in 6th grade?  You should review the [suggestions for good story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) in case they help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: How long ago were you in 6th grade? 5 years? 10 years? 25 years? 50 years?

Answer (score 14):

That could be [*The Lotus Caves*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lotus_Caves) by John Christopher, 1969.

The plot of [*The Lotus Caves*](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/c/john-christopher/lotus-caves.htm) seems to match the plot points outlined in the question - two YA's take an unauthorised joyride after stealing access to a moon-buggy, they eventually discover a cave system (not another dome, which is a discrepancy) made habitable by an alien plant that forms an artificial ecosystem.

Comment: Assuming this is correct (which it almost certainly is), this is a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/200422/childrens-sci-fi-book-about-joyriding-a-space-craft/

Comment: The discrepancy mentioned in the answer above is due to them first visiting the dome of the original moonbase, where they discover a clue to the disappearance of one of the original astronauts. When they follow the directions found in an old notebook they find the caves.

Answer (score 2):

It it "Emlyn's Moon"?

In that book, set in Wales, a girl called Nia and a boy called Emlyn set off to find his mother and *brother* who he suspects are on the moon, in the first book of the trilogy, *The Snow Spider*, Gwyn's sister comes back but returns to where Emylyn's mam and dad are.